# Wix3 MSI dialog title doesn't show version by default?

Tags: c#, wix

I tried to overwrite the localization properties in WixUI_xxx.wxl, it worked. But there are a lot properties need to be changed.

Adding version in ProductName is a workaround, but not nice.

Do you know a easy way to let MSI dialog show version?

Comment: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/

Comment: Not found a clue in the document.